# Selecting elements that are not inside certain elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

Using CSS3, is there a way to select elements that are not within elements with a certain class? For example, in the example below, how do I select `class="bar"` elements that are not inside elements of `class="foo"` (i.e., `id="2"` but not `id="1"`)?

```
<div class="foo">
  ... arbitrary depth ...
    <div class="bar" id="1">
      ...
    </div>
  ...
</div>
...
  <div class="bar" id="2">
    ...
  </div>
...
```

Comment: not for arbitrafy depth, CSS only. you can always use `.foo .bar` styles to negate previous `.bar` styles

Comment: @deathApril: Sounds like you should post a new answer instead. By the way, that link you cited in your deleted answer is bad; I'd recommend against ever referring to it.

Comment: As of 2023, this is possible with the :has() pseudo-class. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Answer (score 3):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anot), `:not()` will match an element according to some conditions, it won't return a "non-element".

I don't know any pseudoselectors to test **all parents** for some condition, so I would personally use a workaround like this:

```
div {background: yellow;}
.bar {background: green;}
.foo .bar {background: yellow;} /*repeat original styles changed by .bar*/
```

Comment: It will match an element that *doesn't* satisfy a certain condition, e.g. `:not(x)` will match any element that isn't `x`.

Answer (score 1):

### If `.foo` itself is not arbitrarily deep

Assuming `.foo` *is a known depth from the `body` tag* (your question only indicates arbitrary depth *within* `.foo`, or for `.bar` regardless of in or out of `.foo`), then something like the following code works to select any `.bar` for any arbitrary depth inside or outside of `.foo`. For this first example, I'm assuming `.foo` is a direct child of `body`, but if it were not, then the code would have to be slightly modified to accommodate the appropriate depth of `.foo` (see second example):

```
body > :not(.foo) .bar,
body > .bar {
    /* styles */
}
```

[**See a fiddle for the above code.**](http://jsfiddle.net/QAb9C/2/)

This is only practical if `.foo` is not nested too deep, as `.bar` positioning must be accounted for at both the same level as `.foo` and any previous levels higher. So, for example, if `.foo` was a grandchild of `body`, then the following would be needed:

```
body > * > :not(.foo) .bar, /* deeper levels checking for no .foo parent */
body > .bar, /* child level */
body > * > .bar { /* grandchild level; equal to .foo's level */
    /* styles */
}
```

[**See a fiddle for the above code.**](http://jsfiddle.net/QAb9C/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, the only way to get this to work would be to use the :not syntax and specify 1 layer of depth by element or class name

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2V7Wc/

html

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar" id="one">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bar" id="two">
</div>
```

css:

```
.bar:not(#one) {
   /* styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following:

```
.bar {
    color:red;
}

.foo ~ .bar{
    color:green;
}
```

See this demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/QR3kP/

Comment: nice for this particular example, not sure about the "arbitrary" depth condition

Comment: that's true! however in your case, you can utilize the IDs you set.

Comment: Not really the question. How about a bar appearing before the foo ? How about a bar appearing after the foo but not being a sibling (inside another div, for instance)